# How to add Column in existing table in asp Boilerplate?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

As you know Boilerplate don't give the entity classes to add columns and I want to add column in table named ( AbpUser). I tried to make a class in Migrations like below

```
public partial class AddRatingMig : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.AbpUsers", "UserType", c => c.String());
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.AbpUsers", "UserType");
    }
}
```

Then in Pm console run command Update-Database
  . But not successful. As you know Boilerplate don't give the entity classes to edit columns. Please Help Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [ask] and learn about what is on-topic to ask here. Your question is very broad. It is expected that you've already made an attempt at solving your problem before asking here. I would look at some tutorials online and then if you have trouble implementing it, come back here and ask a more specific question with a [mcve],

Comment: I asked a simple question. Its about a specific framework, if you know about Boilerplate framework then guide please...

Comment: You did not ask a question that is within the guidelines on this site. If you read through the [help], you would have been aware of that.

Comment: Then you aren't likely to get an answer. If you aren't going to take the time to write a good question, why should a volunteer take the time to write a good answer to an off-topic question?

Comment: Check now @Lexi . I am not good in English but tried to explain my problem

Comment: The answer to this question is to Extend the AbpUser like this     public class User : AbpUser<User>
    {
 public string SpecialTitle  { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: @Vince I did all which you are telling.. But got an error on running in browser

Comment: Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed.

Comment: @Vince after enabling Migrations and updating database. I found solution. Thanks man. Please write your above answer in answer pane so i can mark it true. Thanks again

Comment: there is no restriction to extend the user class. you can extend it by inheriting.  

[Table("AbpTenants")] 
public class MyUser : User 
{ 
 
}

Comment: please read the document. it's explained very good in docs. https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/installation?searchKey=user

Comment: Yes i got that. thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this question is to Extend the AbpUser like this

```
public class User : AbpUser<User> 
{ 
    public string SpecialTitle { get; set; } 
}
```

and add-migration UpdatedUserWithSpecialTitle
then update-database

Comment: I have a new question... how to do search on database table in Boilerplate? it uses async methods

Comment: and as i mention in first question Boilerplate does not provide entity classes

Comment: I want to search on existing tables

Comment: You should create a new question about it and I will answer it my best, because we need to keep this post on the question

Comment: Please check link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912587/asp-net-boilerplate-how-to-update-a-record-in-existing-tables-in-database-usi

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way

```
public partial class AddRatingMig : DbMigration
 {
    public override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
  {
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
      name: "UserType",
      table:"AbpUsers",
      nullable:true
      );
  }

    public override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
      {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
        name:"UserType",
        table:"dbo.AbpUsers"
        );
      }
}
```

Hence update Database using code as: update-database

**NOTE:**

Make sure that you have properly added migrations as:
`add-migration migration_name`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in abp.io framework, adding new property, "PICUstomerId" to AbpUser Entity and migrate it to database.

Here is the comments by abp.io:

Add your own properties here. Example:

public string MyProperty { get; set; }
If you add a property and using the EF Core, remember these;

1. Update PasargadInsuranceDbContext.OnModelCreating to configure the mapping for your new property
2. Update PasargadInsuranceEfCoreEntityExtensionMappings to extend the         IdentityUser entity and add your new property to the migration.
3. Use the Add-Migration to add a new database migration.
4. Run the .DbMigrator project (or use the Update-Database command) to apply schema change to the database.

and finally add-migration to your solution and then update-database

[1. Add your own properties here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4bVv.png)

[2. Update PasargadInsuranceDbContext.OnModelCreating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ3yg.png)

[3. Update PasargadInsuranceEfCoreEntityExtensionMappings to extend theIdentityUser entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WewXv.png)

[4. And finally after update-databse, I saw my new property in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz8Qk.png)