# Asp.Net Boilerplate... How to update a record in Existing tables in Database using Async methods?

Tags: c#, async-await, ef-code-first, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I am working with *ASP.Net Boilerplate*. I want to send `isActive=true` to the `AbpUser` table when a user is confirmed by email. How can I access the database and do a query on that?

As you know *Boilerplate* doesn't provide entity classes so I am working with extensions on those classes. I don't know how queries on those classes access the database. Any idea?

Comment: why do you think ABP doesn't provide entity classes. you have to read the docs.. https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entities?searchKey=entity

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a sample code to show you how you can update a field of user with IRepository.

```
public interface IUserAppService: IApplicationService
{
    void ActivateUser(int userId);
}
```

---

```
 public class UserAppService : IUserAppService
    {
        private readonly IRepository<User, long> _userRepository;

        public UserEmailer(IRepository<User, long> userRepository)
        {
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }

        public void ActivateUser(int userId)
        {
            var user = _userRepository.Get(userId);
            user.IsActive = true;
            _userRepository.Update(user);
        }
}
```

Comment: It's the way to go! PO must know that when the Entity have a ID type other than "int" it must provide the type as second argument to the repository.